# MySQL how to count the results of a count?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I construct a query in MySQL to count the results of a group? So,

Table A

```
Month    Item
Jan         1
Jan         3
Feb         2
Feb         2
Mar         3
```

Table B

```
Item   Color
1       red
1       blue
2       black
3       black
3       yellow
```

I want a query that will tell me how many items in Table A exist in Table B where there are at least two colors in each month. In other words, how many items have I sold in each month where there are more than 2 colors. So the result would be:

```
Month  Results
Jan      2
Feb      0
Mar      1
```

Thank you.

Comment: what do you have so far? please edit your question to include any attempt you've made however half-baked

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, I think the following answers it:

```
select a.month,
       (case when count(distinct b.color) >= 2 then COUNT(distinct a.item) else 0 end)
from TableA a join
     TableB b
     on a.item = b.item
group by a.month
```

This counts the total number of colors in a month.  If 2 or greater, then it has the number of items.  Otherwise, it has 0.

Comment: This counts distinct *colours per month*, while the OP seems to be after the number of *items per month*, each item having at least two colours. I don't think this can be done without two-level grouping.

Comment: I didn't carefully check this answer when I gave mine... but it's a nice idea.. +1

Comment: @AndriyM . . . We interpret this statement differently "where there are at least two colors in each month".  Now that I see your interpretation, it also makes sense.  The person asking the question should really clarify.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! I was too preoccupied with my own reading of the question, sorry. Your reading makes perfect sense to me, so yes, it's up to the OP really.

Answer (score 1):

This subquery returns all of the items that have at least two colors:

```
select Item
from TableB
group by Item
having count(distinct Color)>1
```

And you can join it with TableA, and the resulting query is this:

```
select
  A.Month,
  Count(B.Item)
from
  TableA A left join (
    select Item
    from TableB
    group by Item
    having count(distinct Color)>1) B
  on A.Item=B.Item
group by A.Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.Month, COALESCE(T2.Cnt2,0) Cnt
FROM (
   SELECT Month
   FROM TableA
) T LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT A.Month, COUNT(DISTINCT B.Color) Cnt, COUNT(DISTINCT B.Item) Cnt2
   FROM TableA A
      INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.Item = B.Item
   GROUP BY A.Month
   HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT B.Color) >= 2
) T2 ON T.Month = T2.Month
```

It Uses `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` Items in TableA and TableB.  To return Feb 0, you need the `LEFT JOIN`.

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/410a5/1).

Good luck.